# Group Position in Corona

Tags: object, position, coronasdk

I have a few codes below.

```
local mBackground = loader:loadBackground()
localGroup:insert(mBackground)

local mAnimals = loader:loadAnimal()
localGroup:insert(mAnimals)

local mDoor = loader:loadDoor()
localGroup:insert(mDoor)
```

The animals should always be left behind the door, but it can be updated by running the load function of loader few times. 
I want to keep them behind the door whenever they are updated. How can I do that?

I used `toBack()`, but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toBack()` will make the object to the back of the group

`toFront()` will make the object to the front of the group

There is no way to move the object 1 index backward or forward, like move forward or move backward.

The method on your case will be this

```
mAnimals:toFront()
mDoor:toFront()
```

It's a little bit brute force, but it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can put an object on different index group buy doing this

```
local mBackground = loader:loadBackground()
localGroup:insert(1,mBackground) -- move object from index 1

local mAnimals = loader:loadAnimal()
localGroup:insert(2,mAnimals) -- move object from index 2

local mDoor = loader:loadDoor()
localGroup:insert(3,mDoor) -- move object from index 3
```

you can even change/update it's index if you want or put the same object in the same index